# the error with using angularfire2 v4

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm trying to build something with new angularfire2 version, but having trouble after trouble. Now I'm stuck at the following error:
Failed to compile.

```
./~/firebase/app/shared_promise.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'promise-polyfill' in 'my 
directory.../node_modules/firebase/app'
@ ./~/firebase/app/shared_promise.js 37:35-62
@ ./~/firebase/app/firebase_app.js
@ ./~/firebase/app.js
@ ./~/firebase/database.js
@ ./~/angularfire2/database/firebase_list_factory.js
@ ./~/angularfire2/database.js
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Try deleting your node modules and reinstalling them.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by going in my package.json file and changing the firebase dependency to ^3.6.6.
After doing that, save the file and run npm install again.
Hope it helps.